# Scrapy Get Image Xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I try to get image url from here _https://kirpich-s.ru/catalog/kirpich-ruchnoj-formovki-seriya-standart/1 and use this code:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/img/@src').get()
```

But it doesn't work. I think that my xpath is wrong but I get it trought chrome console. Could you tell is problem with xpath or with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xpath to identify.

```
//img[contains(@src,'foto/brick-handmade')]/@src
```

code:

```
response.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'foto/brick-handmade')]/@src").get()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working. But could you explain how to make this xpath from Chrome?

Comment: Next page has not the same folders https://kirpich-s.ru/catalog/kirpich-ruchnoj-formovki-seriya-standart/aj-petri. Is it possible to use another method?